# deleted Database data comming back overnight

Tags: sql-server, table

I am a developer i am facing a situation where Web Application deletes data, on the next morning the deleted data is back on the Database. Yesterday some of our users spent the whole day deleting outdated records on the database only to workup today to findout that the data is back on the tables. So far this is happening on one table. The table doesnt have a unique identifier.  I am developer my skills on the database processes are limited, How can i trace the process that does this?

Comment: You need to provide lot of details before anyone could really guess the reason. Did you check manually after deleting from webapplication that mentioned data from table was deleted? Is there any trigger defined on table? Any nightly job for subject table? May be, this database gets restored from some where else?

Comment: Check triggers and check constrain in table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL2014 and up, you can setup an extended event that will track activity on this specific table.

That way, if something re-write the data in the table, you should be able to see where it is comming from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events?view=sql-server-ver15